What causes git fetch to consistently fail with "fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/mybranch?" inside a Windows docker container on K8S?
I'm running into a bizzare issue when i'm trying to (as part of a CI job, so non-interactively) rebase a branch i've just committed to, when that branch has been changed by another job upstream.
What happens is this:

I clone my repository, with the --branch my-branch option to only pick the branch I want to modify
I spend a bunch of time (30-60 minutes) making some code changes, and commit these to my local branch.
I then run git push to push this commit up, but it fails because some other job has pushed to the remote in the meantime.
I run git fetch origin my-branch to update the reference to the remote - and I would then run GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase -Xtheirs origin/my-branch to non-interactively rebase my local my-branch onto the remote.

This all runs fine on Ubuntu CI jobs running inside a kubernetes container, but on Windows K8S pods, and only on my specific repository (its working with a bunch of other repositories with no issues).
My git fetch command fails with this (i've enabled GIT_TRACE)
git.c:463               trace: built-in: git fetch origin my-branch
run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://***@github.com/my-user/my-repository.git
git.c:750               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://***@github.com/my-user/my-repository.git
run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://***@github.com/my-user/my-repository.git
run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git unpack-objects -q --pack_header=2,61
git.c:463               trace: built-in: git unpack-objects -q --pack_header=2,61
run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --exclude-hidden=fetch --all --quiet --alternate-refs
git.c:463               trace: built-in: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --exclude-hidden=fetch --all --quiet --alternate-refs
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/my-branch?
error: https://github.com/my-user/my-repository.git did not send all necessary objects

I then ran git fsck to shed any more light, and I get this:
git.c:463               trace: built-in: git fsck
error: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/my-branch?: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/other-branch-1?: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/other-branch-2?: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/other-branch-3?: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/other-branch-4?: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
(and one for every single remote branch on the repository)

along with a bunch of dangling commit lines (presumably one for every single remote branch on the repository), followed by git fsck exiting with code 2.
I don't have this problem with the same repository on Ubuntu, and I don't have this problem with other repositories on Windows, so clearly there's something screwed up with my repository on Windows, but I don't know what it could be?
I've enabled git config --global core.longpaths true before cloning (besides, if I didn't set this, it doesn't even clone). What I don't understand is that if it doesn't need to rebase, then it pushes up the new commit totally fine, and there's nothing weird in that commit, just some text file changes.
Why is it only the subsequent fetch that has these consistent issues? If there was something wrong with the repsitory, wouldn't it fail to clone in the first place?
And where are all these ? on the end of the references coming from?
Is there anything I can attempt to do to fix the issue that would then let me continue to rebase?
